# XCode 4 -> Quick way to jump (or switch) to super class

Tags: xcode, xcode4

If we press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>up arrow</kbd> we switch between file code and header code. (.m to .h)

If we press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> or <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>mouse click</kbd> we jump to definition of variable. But it not work for **super**.

So, there are a fast way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Command + Shift + D.  Jump to definition.  Does that work?

Also check out the link bellow.  It lists a bunch of Xcode keyboard shortcuts.
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_help-command_shortcuts/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010560-CH1-SW1

Answer (score 6):

I'm a little late to the party, but here's a good method for seeing both superclasses and subclasses.  Click on the related files icon.  It looks like this:  [image: Related Files Icon] and you'll find it in the upper left of the edit window.  You'll get a menu of many kinds of related files among which will be the superclass and subclass lists.

You can also open that menu using Ctrl+1, if you happen to be a keyboard person.